# jenkins build docker images

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes

I'm going to use jenkins to build images and then deploy to kubernetes.

I have a problem about building. We have a lot of programs written in c++, java, nodejs, php, golang and etc.

How should I support all kinds of build ?

Comment: Maybe you should detail your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through the [Jenkins Swarm plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Swarm+Plugin), you can define and use a Jenkins slave with the various language tools pre-installed.

See [`docker-jenkins-slave`](https://github.com/helios-technologies/docker-jenkins-slave), which includes a [Dockerfile installing the lanaguages compilators](https://github.com/helios-technologies/docker-jenkins-slave/blob/master/docker/Dockerfile.erb).

You can then start a slave:

```
docker run -d -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock heliostech/jenkins-slave-docker \
  -master http://jenkins-server/ -username JENKINS_USER -password JENKINS_USER_KEY \
  -executors 2 -labels "docker"
```